# Salesforce 1 Security Question

Tags: salesforce1-app, security

While going through the login history for the last 6 months, I could see numerous users of our organization utilizing Salesforce 1 for accessing our CRM instance.

Whats our concern is that many of the mobile devices (Android/ioS) may not even have a phone lock on them ?.

Anyone who can access these mobile devices without a phonelock on them will potentially be able to access our CRM system.

Can someone tell me what can be done in this case ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure S1 to require a pin code, see the settings under Setup -> Manage Apps -> Connected Apps -> Salesforce 1 for iOS (or Salesforce 1 for Android) You can edit this to set a timeout for requiring a PIN code, along with the minimum pin code length, once set the users should get prompted to create a pin code specific to the app.